# Convert Spark Dataframe to XML files

Tags: xml, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Dose anyone know how to convert Spark DataFrames to XML format? If you could provide some example codes, that would be awesome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this package as it includes the code needed for conversion from a dataframe to xml. [Spark-xml](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml)

Comment: i thought this is reading xml to dataframe, but i would like to convert dataframe to xml format.

Comment: Hey Michelle, Please look at this section. https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#conversion-from-dataframe-to-xml. The examples follow the conversion in both directions.